# python: What does nan_policy=omit do for scipy.stat.spearmanr

Tags: python, scipy

```
scipy.stats.spearmanr([1,2,3,4,1],[1,2,2,1,np.nan],nan_policy='omit')
```

it will give a spearman correlation of 0.349999
My understanding is that nan_policy ='omit' will discard all the pairs which have nan. If that's the case, the results should be the same as `scipy.stats.spearmanr([1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1])`
However, it gives a correlation of 0.235702. 
Why are they different? Is my understand of nan_policy ='omit' corrent?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code, it gives me cero correlation (R=0.0).
I use this function and you are understanding well `nan_policy ='omit'`.

If you don't need the p-value of the correlation I would sugest using `.corr(method = 'spearman')` from pandas library. By default it excludes NA/null values.

[Official Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

Answer (score 0):

`nan_policy='omit'` should completely omit those pairs for which one or both values are nan. When I run the two commands you pasted above, I get the same correlation value, not different ones.